# Search text for valid Python code

Tags: python

I have chunks of text that may or may not contain Python code. I need a way to search the text for code and if it is there, do something. I could easily search for specific strings that match a regex, but I need something general.

One thought I had would be to run the text through `ast`, but that would require parsing out all possible substrings and submitting each of them to `ast`.

To be clear, the text comes from a Q&A forum for Python. Users frequently post code in their questions, but the code is all smushed into one long, incoherent line when it should be formatted to be displayed properly. I need to check if there is code included in the text and if there is and it isn't formatted properly, complain to the user. Checking formatting is something I can handle, I just need to check the text for any Python code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of code are we talking, some basic or more advanced?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid". A regex (as part of a scanner) can only check if the tokens are valid (you didn't use emjos as a variable, e.g.). A parser can check that its gramatical; that still won't check that it's "valid" as in "will run", which would require some semantic analysis and an ast. One way would be (if you know everything's safe), to just try and run whatever you think is valid. If it runs, it was valid. If it doesn't, it probably wasn't valid

Comment: I voted as unclear. Without any test cases "may or may not contain valid Python code"  means absolutely nothing. Any code proposed in responses, paraphising you, may or may not work.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python pylint will tell you if there is syntax error...

Comment: Generally, you'll want to do two passes. The first one should be fast and give back chunks that may be Python code, the second pass would involve calling `ast.parse`.  You'll make your life much more enjoyable if you can help he first pass by requiring surrounding syntax (e.g. empty lines, @begin-python, or some-such).

Comment: The text would come from a Q&A forum for Python and the goal is to help users format their code properly. They have a tendency to write code on one long line when it should be separated out or easily formatted with spaces (like on here). The code in question will be encased in surrounding noise. So I guess the problem is more if the text contains *any* Python code, not just valid Python code.